# TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED unable to swap token to token uniswap

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix

I am trying to swap using WETH from my contract to DAI using `swapExactTokensForTokens(amountIn, amountOutMin, getPathForETHtoToken(tokenAddress), address(this), deadline)` with uniswap. First I approved large amount on both DAI and WETH address then I deposited 0.01 worth of WETH using:

```
function wrap() public payable restricted {
    if (msg.value != 0) {
      WETH.deposit{value : msg.value}();
      WETH.transfer(address(this), msg.value);
    }
  }
```

on my contract and now able to see the balance in WETH
Next on remix I filled out the parameters for my swap function

```
function Buy(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, uint deadline, address tokenAddress) external payable restricted {
    uniswapRouter.swapExactTokensForTokens(amountIn, amountOutMin, getPathForETHtoToken(tokenAddress), address(this), deadline);
}

// amountIn = 10000000000000000, amountOutMin = 4029840000000000000, etc
```

And when I execute I get this error

```
Fail with error 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED'
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to call `approve` on the `from` token again, just before calling swap